# How to update UI when SQLiteDatabase changes without ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to update my ListView controlled by some type of adapter and I want it to update when my SQLiteDatabase changes.
The database only needs to be used in this application.

I'm stuck in this loop,
-People recommend using SimpleCursorAdapter, but
-Android Docs recommends not using a ContentProvider if the SQLiteDatabase is only used in one application.
-SimpleCursorAdapter needs a ContentProvider-uri.

Any suggestions which adapter, loader, links to use?

Comment: I recommend Dao and Observer patterns.

Comment: I like GreenDao for SqLite stuff. Observer pattern is correct for updating ui.

Comment: @bigdestroyer thanks, I found this tutorial on Observer patterns. [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html)

Comment: It's perfect. You can suscribe your adapter (observer) to your DAO (subject),  for example. When the DAO do any change on database, it will notify to the observers, the adapter in your case, and adapter will update the listview with new data.

Comment: Trying to make an adapter which extends SimpleCursorAdapter and implements PropertyChangeListener and the adapter is using DAO inside. When DAO changes I'm trying to change the cursor to a new one. Problem with this is that if I change the DAO from another activity, the adapter reference (listener) in DAO is null (because the activity closed?) So I can't notify.

Comment: So you'd use oberserver patterns in a tabbed view instead rebuliding the view each time?

Which class would you use as subject?